# How do ICMP packets travel in a networks?

Tags: ip, protocol-theory, icmp, rfc

Questions:

I'd like to know how ICMP packets travel in a network? Are they encapsulated within IP datagram?

The RFC 792 doesn't explicitly states the layer of ICMP. Are ICMP messages sent using a header of their own? Which layer does ICMP belong to in TCP/IP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed specified in [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792), on the top of page 2:

> Message Formats
>
> > ICMP messages are sent using the basic IP header.

You will also found in this RFC :

> ICMP, uses the basic support of IP as if it were a higher level
> protocol, however, ICMP is actually an integral part of IP,

AS for the layer, sees this related quesiton: [Why is the ICMP protocol considered to run at layer 3 on the Wikipedia page?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28707/16930)

which explain why ICMP is in fact a layer 3 protocol.